# need help to understand the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In one of the books, it was mentioned

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^3 \tan x)= (x^2\sec^3x+3x^2\tan x)$, but i think it should be $(x^3\sec^2x+3x^2\tan x)$.

I feel its a printing mistake. Just wanted to be sure, if that's not the case, can you please tell me how do we get $(x^2\sec^3x+3x^2\tan x)$?

-Kamal.

Comment: You are right. It is a typo.

Comment: You are perfectly correct ! One more typo in a textbook ! Cheers.

Comment: Got it thanks to all :).

Answer (score 0):

Using the product rule,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dx}(x^3\tan(x))=3x^2\tan(x)+x^3\sec^2(x)
\end{equation*}
because $\frac{d}{dx}(\tan(x))=\sec^2(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)=3x^2$. So yes, you are right. There is a typo in this book. $~_{\square}$